# clearing text in button android studio

Tags: android

Here is my code

button.getText().clear();[error in clear()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8FKK.png)

clear is in red color and android studio is not recognizing.please help me to clear text in buttons

Comment: button.setText("") will work for you!

Comment: you want to clear the text of button?

Comment: Thanks a lot.It worked

Answer (score 1):

you should use

> button.setText("");

Answer (score 0):

```
button.getText().clear()
```

**.getText()** for get text (String) from button so change it, to **button.setText("")**  function for set text from button **.setText("ure change text")**